# django redirect variable to index

Tags: django, variables, redirect

Im a bit new to django and working on the user handling.
Now have i sorted it all and it works just fine, except for when a user enters faulthy data to login.
No errormessage is shown.
I was wondering if there would be a easier/better approach to fix this then putting a empty variable in all my views, except the invalid login. (to store the message in)

My auth_view:

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    #returns None if not correct
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        invalid_login = "ErrorMessage"
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index')
```

index is just this at the moment:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

How can i solve this? (or would you suggest i just approach it with the extra var everywhere)

With kind regards
Hans

Comment: A login form with some validations perhaps is in order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved it:

```
def index(request):
    """Logs a user into the application."""
    auth_form = AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST or None)

    # The form itself handles authentication and checking to make sure passowrd and such are supplied.
    if auth_form.is_valid():
        login(request, auth_form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'auth_form': auth_form}
```

Now problem is my style class from css doesnt seem to work anymore.

But well we are getting there

(used the UserAuthenticationForm here